# What exactly is the difference between has_many, has_and_belongs_to_many and embeds_many in mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I understand this not a programming problem, I am unable to find a very clear and descriptive solution.

Comment: People who are giving negative vote, will they care to give a reason ?

Answer (score 14):

Mongoid's [documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html) is quite clear:

> **Embedded relations** describe documents who are stored inside other documents in the database.
>
> **Referenced relations** describe documents that reference documents in another collection by storing foreign key data (usually an id) about the other document in itself.

In detail:

#### Referenced 1-n / [`has_many`](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_many)

When defining a relation of this nature, each document is stored in its respective collection, but the child document contains a "foreign key" reference to the parent.

```
# The parent band document.
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7e9") }

# The child member document.
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7f1"),
  "band_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7e9")
}
```

#### Referenced n-n / [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_and_belongs_to_many)

When defining a relation of this nature, each document is stored in its respective collection, and each document contains a "foreign key" reference to the other in the form of an array.

```
# The band document.
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7e9"),
  "tag_ids" : [ ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7f2") ]
}

# The tag document.
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7f2"),
  "band_ids" : [ ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7e9") ]
}
```

#### Embedded 1-n / [`embeds_many`](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#embeds_many)

Documents that are embedded using the `embeds_many` macro are stored as an array of hashes inside the parent in the parent's database collection.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7e9"),
  "albums" : [
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7e0"),
      "name" : "Violator",
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: he did not want has_and_belongs_to_many he wants has_many and belongs_to many look at his header carefully

Comment: @RajarshiDas the OP asks for the difference between `has_many`, `has_many_and_belongs_to_many` (sic) and `embeds_many`

Answer (score 0):

Embeds_many will link to your object many time a collection as embedded objects (1:N)
Has_many will do the same, but not as embedded objects (1:N)

The last one will mostly be the equivalent of (N:N)